# Заполнение бд на mysql с помощью CSV файла

Tags: python

возникла ошибка в скрипте при добавлении данных из .csv файла в MySQL бд. Ошибка состоит в том, что пайтон неправильно передает значение столбика из .csv [INT -> %d] а SQL думает что значение=строка -> %d, а формат столбика INT. Как правильно передать параметр int из .csv в INT MySQL?

.csv 1строка

> 160942891 Muni Inspection 2016-04-03T00:00:00 2016-04-03T00:00:00 2016-04-03T00:00:00 18:15 2016-04-03T18:15:00 Not recorded 900 Block Of Ulloa St San Francisco CA 1 Common Location West Portal Muni, Sf

.csv 238строка

> 160913103 Encampment 2016-03-31T00:00:00 2016-03-31T00:00:00 2016-03-31T00:00:00 18:57 2016-03-31T18:57:00 ADV 2700 Block Of Folsom St San Francisco CA 1 Premise Address

```
import MySQLdb
import csv

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.1.2",
                     port=3306,
                     user="non-root-boy",
                     passwd="123456",
                     db="sfpd")

print ("\nConnection to DataBase established..\n")
cur = db.cursor()

f = open('/home/decoy/Downloads/police-department-calls-for-service.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    if len(row) < 12:
        continue
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO crimes(`Crime Id`, `Original Crime Type
Name`, \
`Report Date`, `Call Date`, `Offense Date`, `Call          Time`, \
`Call Date Time`, `Disposition`, `Address`, `City`, `State`, `Agency Id`, \
`Address Type`, `Common Location`) VALUES(%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, \
                  %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s)", row)
print ("Done")
```

При запуске данного кода возникают данные ошибки:

> Connection to DataBase established..
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 238, in
>   execute query = query % args TypeError: %d format: a number is
>   required, not str
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/home/decoy/Projects/Python/sfpdBASE_insert.py", line 25, in %s, %s,
>   %s, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s)", row) File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 240, in
>   execute self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, str(m)) File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 52, in
>   defaulterrorhandler raise errorclass(errorvalue)
>   _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: %d format: a number is required, not str
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: почему бы не загружать напрямую через клиента майскул?

Comment: покажите таблицу